# Wrong block height?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

When I press 'Show status' in the GUI the daemon seems to report the wrong block height:

```
Height: 1055339/1055339 (100.0%) on testnet, not mining, net hash 9.45 kH/s, v6, up to date, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 7m 24s

Height: 1055340/1055340 (100.0%) on testnet, not mining, net hash 9.55 kH/s, v6, up to date, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 8m 6s

Height: 1055346/1055346 (100.0%) on testnet, not mining, net hash 9.60 kH/s, v6, up to date, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 13m 0s

Height: 1055350/1055350 (100.0%) on testnet, not mining, net hash 9.65 kH/s, v6, up to date, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 17m 48s
```

From what I understand the current block height should be around 1.4million. I also cannot see any balance in my account, despite having done a test transaction through shapeshift a few days ago

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I was using the test network by mistake. When creating or restoring a wallet you need to untick the 'Testnet' checkbox, which is on by default. Silly me.